# Add bitmap for NULLs in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

**Table1**

```
USER_ID     NAME    AGE     GENDER  ZIP_CODE
1           John    33      M       01086       
2           NULL    22      M       01247
3           Brown   NULL    F       01581
```

I want to add a bitmap as a column at the end.

```
USER_ID     NAME    AGE     GENDER  ZIP_CODE   NULL_COLUMN
1           John    33      M       01086      00000
2           NULL    22      M       01247      01000
3           Brown   NULL    F       01581      00100
```

The logic is

> If value other than NULL, assign 0
>
> If value = NULL, assign 1

Also, if I make a column NULL, then it needs to update the NULL_COLUMN, in the following way:

```
Update table1 set name = NULL;
```

**Table1**

```
USER_ID     NAME    AGE     GENDER  ZIP_CODE   NULL_COLUMN
1           NULL    33      M       01086      01000
2           NULL    22      M       01247      01000
3           NULL    NULL    F       01581      01100
```

Is there a way in Oracle SQL to create the NULL_COLUMN using the conditions and update it as the values become NULL?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can query which columns are `NULL` by name without needing a separate (and denormalized!) column.

Comment: Also, to clarify, by "bitmap" you're referring to how the RDBMS stores information about `NULL` values in each row, right? You're not referring to a Bitmap Index?

Comment: @Dai - yes - I am referring to bitmap and not bitmap index. I'm doing this as meta information for each record for my QC.

Comment: @nikhilsugandh - yes, two rows can have same null value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generated column:

```
alter table table1
    add null_map generated always as (nvl2(userJ_id, '1', '0') || nvl2(name, '1', '0') || nvl2(age, '1', '') || nvl2(gender, '1', '') || nvl2(zip_code, '1', '0'));
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return a `varchar` value rather than a true bitfield/bitmap?

Comment: @Dai . . Oracle doesn't have a data type called "bitmap".  Although this could be implemented using a number, that would limit the number of columns -- a string is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a concat for NVL2

```
select USER_ID 
,NAME
,AGE
,GENDE
,ZIP_CODE
, '0' || NVL2( NAME, '1', '0' ) || 
  NVL2( AGE, '1', '0' ) ||
  NVL2( GENDER, '1', '0' ) || 
  NVL2( ZIP_CODE, '1', '0' ) NULL_COLUMN
```

from my_table